# CAKEPHP help on running project in ubuntu

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu, debian

I have a project that it is deploy and running on Debian (apache 2.2.9, php5.2, mysql 5.0) 
Now i trying to run it in ubuntu 11.10(apache 2.2 php 5.3 mysql 5.1) but only the homepage is working.

If i click on any of the links I get the *Not Found* page:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /patients was not found on this server.

Does anybody have an idea why it is doing this?

I basically check everything, I can't figure out why.

I have a feeling it has to do with cakephp.

Comment: First make sure you deploy your project in the right place.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with mod_rewrite. Maybe this helps: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable mod_rewrite in Apache.

Run this command in terminal: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, another I had to do for a fresh install was `sudo a2enmod headers`. Afterwards, you'll need to restart Apache, the terminal will tell you what command you have to run to do that.